# Is it possible to power down my external via the eject button?

Tags: gnome, mount, 12.10, eject

I'm trying to convert from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome 3.6.

Using the notification area's eject icon, I notice the partition is unmounted but the drive is still powered and spinning...

I understand the latter can be taken care of by means of

```
udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

I really don't want to have to run a command everytime I eject. Windows does the whole process when ejecting a medium via the systray.

Is there a way I could add in the command to the eject button? Is there an appropriate place I could file a feature request?

Little things like this are making it hard for me to swap back over to Linux.

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

In 12.04 we can use Nautilus in order to right click the device in the "Devices" list and choose "Safely Remove Drive" option in the context menu as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

Note that there is also the "Eject" option, which acts the same as when using the notification area's eject icon. Nevertheless, the "Safely Remove Drive" in Nautilus physically ejects the device, leaving the device without power, thus shutting it down.

You clearly tagged your question under 12.10 but I won't move to 12.10 soon, and I can't say if the things have changed that much in Nautilus but give this a try and inform us how is Nautilus managing your devices when safely ejected.

Good luck!

Comment: "Physically ejects" means the USB cable should pop out of the machine. Wouldn't that be nice?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, Geppettvs! Unfortunately my Nautilus 3.4.2 only has an "Unmount" option where the "Eject" used to be. Will look into other available versions. That would be awesome, Mike :)

Comment: Mega LOL!!! This time I have exceeded my own expectations... hahahaha XD